# Are there uint64 literals in Go?

Tags: go, long-integer, literals, unsigned, uint64

I'm looking at the [numeric types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types) in Go. I want to use uint64 literals. Is this possible in Go?

Here's an example of how I'd like to use uint64 literals:

```
for i := 2; i <= k; i += 1 { // I want i to be a uint64
    ...
}
```

Comment: Relevant section in the specification: [Constants](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants).

Comment: @SalvadorDali what do you mean by "put"? The answer to my original question is no,  there is no such thing as a `uint64` literal in Go. You have to cast to `uint64`, apparently.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can just cast your integer literal to `uint64`.

```
for i := uint64(1); i <= k; i++ {
    // do something
}
```

Alternatively you could initialize `i` outside of the `for` loop, but then it's scoped larger than the loop itself.

```
var i uint64
for i = 1; i <= k; i++ {
    // note the `=` instead of the `:=`
}
// i still exists and is now k+1
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's take a look at the specification for constant: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Constants. This is what they said:

> A constant may be given a type explicitly by a **constant declaration or conversion**, or **implicitly** when used in a variable declaration or an assignment or as an operand in an expression.

And:

> An untyped constant has a *default* type which is the type to which the constant is implicitly converted in contexts where a typed value is required, for instance, in a short variable declaration such as `i := 0` where there is no explicit type. The default type of an untyped constant is `bool`, `rune`, `int`, `float64`, `complex128` or `string` respectively, depending on whether it is a boolean, rune, integer, floating-point, complex, or string constant.

Based on these statements and in the context of your code, the best way to initialize a variable that is not in the default type list like `uint64` it to convert:

```golang
for i := uint64(2); i <= k; i++ {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Great answer with references to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly declare your variables as that type. The int literal will be of type `int` https://play.golang.org/p/OgaZzmpLfB something like `var i uint64` is required. In your example you'd have to change your assignment as well so something like this;

```
var i uint64
for i = 2; i <= k; i += 1 { // I want i to be a uint64
    ...
}
```