# Type inference for numbers in Go

Tags: go

I need to know about how I can infer a number type in Go.

In C++, I can do something like this:

`auto number = 0LL`

With this, the g++ knows that number is a `long long int` variable.

I want to emphasis the **number type** here! Go uses `int` as default type (`int` is `int32` or `int64` depending on machine architecture).

Exists any way that I can define a variable with uint32 or any other number type without declaring explicitly like in the code above? More specifically, using the `:=` constructor?

Obs: I don't know how to call this operation in C++ so I don't know how to search about it in Go.

Comment: The grammar does not indicate that integer literals can contain a type suffix, so as a result you would need to assign or cast to the desired type: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Integer_literals

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376141/are-there-uint64-literals-in-go

Comment: Hi @paddy, I found this post on [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/go/go_constants.htm) website but this really doesn't work (I just tested [this](https://go.dev/play/p/JKCbUv4pHUD) code on go playground right now). In fact, go official docs doesn't have any mention about literal suffix. :(

Comment: Well, that's not what the language specification says. You might want to write to tutorialspoint and point out the error. Personally, I wouldn't bother with that website at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Go, untyped literals are interpreted based on context. If you assign an untyped numeric literal to, say, a `uint32` value, that literal is converted to `uint32`. For short declarations, the declared variable type is determined based on context as well, you have to specify the type explicitly:

```
x:=uint32(123)
```

which is equivalent to

```
var x uint32 = 123
```

or

```
var x = uint32(123)
```